# Deserialising JSON into nested view model in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, viewmodel

I have a nested view model structure:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public List<LegViewModel> Legs {get;set;}
}

public class LegViewModel
{
    public int Length { get; set; }
}
```

I send some JSON to this using jquery post:

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        $("#mybutton").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    Height: 23,
                    Legs: [
                        {
                            Length: 45,
                        }
                    ]
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<button id="mybutton">hello world!</button>
```

I'm posting to this controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(PersonViewModel model)
{
    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

The `Height` of a `PersonViewModel` gets populated, as does the *number* of elements in the `Legs` list, but each `LegViewModel` in the list does not: the `Length` property remains at 0 where I would expect the `Legs` array to contain one element with `Length` 45.

Note that this is also the same when I do not use a list at all: having the following yields a not null `PersonViewModel.Legs property, but still as the`Legs.Length` property as 0:

```
// view model
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public int Height { get; set; }
    //public List<LegViewModel> Legs {get;set;}
    public LegViewModel Leg { get; set; }
}

public class LegViewModel
{
    public int Length { get; set; }
}

// view
$("#mybutton").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            Height: 23,
            Leg: 
                {
                    Length: 45,
                }

        }
    });
})
```

How can I populate a nested view model using JSON?  Is there something I've missed or can MVC not do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that the MVC Model Binder parses your collections properly when sending data with `$.ajax` you need to do two things:

- Set the `contentType` to `'application/json'`
- And your `data` should hold JSON so `JSON.stringify` the data

So here is the correct usage which then can be parsed by the model binder:

```
$("#mybutton").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                Height: 23,
                Legs: [
                    {
                        Length: 45,
                    }
                ]
            })
        });
    });
```