# Posting Collection with Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm writing an asp.net MVC application and decide to try Knockout.js for dynamic UI stuff. It's a great framework it helped me so much so far.

But I faced 2 problems that I can't solve and find any useful information on that.
I'll start with code to show you what I have and then I shall try to explain what I want to achieve.

**C# ViewModel**

[image: Project ViewModel]

---

[image: ProjectServicesViewModel]

---

[image: ProjectPositionsViewModel]

**My HTML/Razor and knockout Module**

```js
var Project = function (project) {
 var self = this;
 self.Id = ko.observable(project ? project.Id : 0);
 self.CustumerCompany = ko.observable(project ? project.CustumerCompany : "");
 self.CustomerRepresentative = ko.observable(project ? project.CustomerRepresentative : "");
 self.ProjectTitle = ko.observable(project ? project.ProjectTitle : "");
 self.WWSNumber = ko.observable(project ? project.WWSNumber : "");
 self.AqStatus = ko.observable(project ? project.AqStatus : "");
 self.Completed = ko.observable(project ? project.Completed : "");
 self.StartDate = ko.observable(project ? project.StartDate : "");
 self.EndDate = ko.observable(project ? project.EndDate : "");
 self.ProjectLeader = ko.observable(project ? project.ProjectLeader : "");
 self.Deputy = ko.observable(project ? project.Deputy : "");
 self.SalesConsultant = ko.observable(project ? project.SalesConsultant : "");
 self.Service = ko.observableArray(project ? project.Service : []);
};

var ProjectService = function (projectService) {
 var self = this;
 self.Id = ko.observable(projectService ? projectService.Id : 0);
 self.Number = ko.observable(projectService ? projectService.Number : "");
 self.Name = ko.observable(projectService ? projectService.Name : "");
 self.Positions = ko.observableArray(projectService ? projectService.Positions : []);
};

var ServicePosition = function (servicePosition) {
 var self = this;
 self.Id = ko.observable(servicePosition ? servicePosition.Id : 0);
 self.Number = ko.observable(servicePosition ? servicePosition.Number : "");
 self.Name = ko.observable(servicePosition ? servicePosition.Name : "");
 self.PerformanceGroup = ko.observable(servicePosition ? servicePosition.PerformanceGroup : "");
 self.PerformanceGroupPrice = ko.observable(servicePosition ? servicePosition.PerformanceGroupPrice : "");
 self.Remarks = ko.observable(servicePosition ? servicePosition.Remarks : "");
};

var ProjectCollection = function () {
 var self = this;

 self.project = ko.observable(new Project());
 self.projectServices = ko.observableArray([new ServicePosition()]);
 self.servicePositions = ko.observableArray([new ServicePosition()]);

 self.addService = function () {
  self.projectServices.push(new ProjectService());
  console.log(self.projectServices);
 };
 self.removeService = function (projectService) {
  self.projectServices.remove(projectService);
 };



 self.saveProject = function () {
  self.project().Service = self.projectServices;
  console.log(self.projectServices);
  console.log(self.project());

  var token = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();

  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/LeistungManager/CreateProject",
   data: { __RequestVerificationToken: token, model: ko.toJS(self.project()) },
   dataType: "json",
   cache: false,
   async: true,
   success: function (response) {

   },
   complete: function (response) {
    console.log(response);
   }
  });
 };

};
ko.applyBindings(new ProjectCollection());
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="widget">
      <div class="widget-heading">
        <h3 class="widget-title">Project Services</h3>
        <div>
          <form class="form-inline">
            <p>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>WWS-Number</label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Number" data-bind="value: $root.Number" />
                <label>WWS-Number</label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Name" data-bind="value: $root.Name" />
                <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: addService">Add</button>
              </div>
            </p>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="widget-body">
        <table data-bind="visible: projectServices().length > 0 " class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>
                Number
              </th>
              <th>
                Service Name
              </th>
              <th>

              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody data-bind="foreach: projectServices">

            <tr>
              <td data-bind="text: $parent.Number"></td>
              <td data-bind="text: $parent.Name"></td>
              <td>
                <button class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" data-bind="click: $root.removeService">Delete</button>
              </td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**My Result looks like**

[image: Design]

**Problem Nr 1**

When I enter all information and adding few project services item's my controller receive model but Service's properties are empty and I can't figure out why? What I'm doing wrong?

[image: Result]

**Problem Nr 2**

Next to Project Service panel ( *see design screenshot* ) I will build another almost the same panel but in that window the same Add To List functionality should depend on which Item I select in Project Service Panel. 
For example:

If I selected first item in Project Service panel on the right should appear panel with ADD button so I can put item to another list. After I put information to one item I can selected another and put there and panel should update based on Project Service selection. 
I can't find anywhere example, article or tutorial how to achieve this kind of result.
Any kind of help with be helpful!

Comment: The controller need to know how to parse your request. you can use `contentType: 'application/json;'` in your ajax option.

Comment: It knows and withou this

Comment: You really need to set the contentType: 'application/json' and stringify your data, so `data: JSON.stringify({ __RequestVerificationToken: token, model: ko.toJS(self.project()) })` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591437/deserialising-json-into-nested-view-model-in-controller . `dataType`  is **only** relevant when you receive data from the server. When you are sending data you need to set the `contentType`

Comment: I create this fiddle [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n9s9ycuk/) at first glance seems that your services.add method has a problem. initially an empty `ProjectService ` is added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some time reading documentation I manage to solve my problem.
So here is working JS code HTML is the same as in my question:

```js
/// <reference path="../jquery-3.1.0.intellisense.js" />


 var ProjectModel = function (project) {
  var self = this;
  self.Id = ko.observable(project ? project.Id : 0);

  self.CustumerCompany = ko.observable(project ? project.CustumerCompany : "");

  self.CustomerRepresentative = ko.observable(project ? project.CustomerRepresentative : "");

  self.ProjectTitle = ko.observable(project ? project.ProjectTitle : "");

  self.WWSNumber = ko.observable(project ? project.WWSNumber : "");

  self.AqStatus = ko.observable(project ? project.AqStatus : "");

  self.Completed = ko.observable(project ? project.Completed : "");

  self.StartDate = ko.observable(project ? project.StartDate : "");

  self.EndDate = ko.observable(project ? project.EndDate : "");

  self.ProjectLeader = ko.observable(project ? project.ProjectLeader : "");

  self.Deputy = ko.observable(project ? project.Deputy : "");

  self.SalesConsultant = ko.observable(project ? project.SalesConsultant : "");

  self.Service = ko.observableArray(project ? project.Service : []);

 };


 // #endregion

 // #region Project Service Model

 var ProjectServiceModel = function (projectService) {
  var self = this;
  self.Id = ko.observable(projectService ? projectService.Id : 0);

  self.Number = ko.observable(projectService ? projectService.Number : "");

  self.Name = ko.observable(projectService ? projectService.Name : "");

  self.Positions = ko.observableArray(projectService ? projectService.Positions : []);

  self.isEditing = ko.observable(true);

  self.isActive = ko.observable(false);

  self.countSelf = ko.computed(function () {
   if (self.Positions().length > 0) {
    return true;
   }
   else {
    return false;
   }

  },
  self);

 };


 // #endregion

 // #region Position Model
 var ServicePositionModel = function (servicePosition) {
  var self = this;
  self.Id = ko.observable(servicePosition ? servicePosition.Id : 0);

  self.Number = ko.observable(servicePosition ? servicePosition.Number : "");

  self.Name = ko.observable(servicePosition ? servicePosition.Name : "");

  self.PerformanceGroup = ko.observable(servicePosition ? servicePosition.PerformanceGroup : "");

  self.PerformanceGroupPrice = ko.observable(servicePosition ? servicePosition.PerformanceGroupPrice : "");

  self.Remarks = ko.observable(servicePosition ? servicePosition.Remarks : "");

  self.isEditing = ko.observable(servicePosition ? servicePosition.isEditing : false);

  self.isActive = ko.observable(false);

 };

 // #endregion


 var ProjectViewModel = function () {
  var self = this;

  self.project = ko.observable(new ProjectModel());

  self.projectServices = ko.observableArray([]);

  // #region InitData

  

  self.selectedPerformanceGroup = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.AqStatusTypeData = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.PerformanceGroupTypeData = ko.observableArray([]);
  $.ajax({
   url: "/LeistungManager/InitializeData",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (json) {
    self.AqStatusTypeData(json.AqStatusType);
    self.PerformanceGroupTypeData(json.PerformanceGroupType);
   }
  });


  self.testOptions = function () {
   
   self.selectedPerformanceGroup;
   debugger;
  }

  // #endregion

  // #region Service Functions
  self.addService = function () {
   var object = new Object();

   object.isEditing = true;
   self.projectServices.push(new ProjectServiceModel(object));

   self.isServiceSelected(false);

  };


  self.saveService = function (projectService) {
   projectService.isEditing(false);

  };

  self.editService = function (projectService) {
   projectService.isEditing(true);

  };

  self.removeService = function (projectService) {
   self.projectServices.remove(projectService);

  };


  self.isServiceSelected = ko.observable(false);

  self.selectedServiceData = ko.observable(new Object());

  self.selectService = function (serviceRowData) {
   if (!serviceRowData.isEditing()) {
    self.isServiceSelected(true);

    serviceRowData.isActive(true);

    self.selectedServiceData(serviceRowData);

   }

  };

  // #endregion


  // #region Position Functions
  self.addPosition = function () {
   var object = new Object();

   object.isEditing = true;
   self.selectedServiceData().Positions.push(new ServicePositionModel(object));

  };


  self.savePosition = function (servicePosition) {
   servicePosition.isEditing(false);

  };

  self.editPosition = function (servicePosition) {
   servicePosition.isEditing(true);

  };

  self.removePosition = function (servicePosition) {
   self.selectedServiceData().Positions.remove(servicePosition);

  };


  self.isPositionSelected = ko.observable(false);

  self.selectedPositionData = ko.observable(ServicePositionModel(new Object()));

  self.selectPosition = function (positionRowData) {
   if (!positionRowData.isEditing()) {
    self.isPositionSelected(true);

    positionRowData.isActive(true);

    self.selectedPositionData(positionRowData);


   }

  };

  // #endregion

  self.saveProject = function () {
   self.project().Service = self.projectServices;
   self.project().Service().Positions = self.servicePositions;

   var token = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();


   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/LeistungManager/CreateProject",
    data: { __RequestVerificationToken: token, model: ko.toJS(self.project()) },

    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    success: function (response) {

    },

    complete: function (response) {
     console.log(response);

    }

   });

  };


 };

ko.applyBindings(new ProjectViewModel());
```

The magic was with creating **selectedServiceData** observable variable and pass it to **selectPosition** function on button click. After that I could work with selected Item arrays and data.

If anybody needs more detailed explanation or help with code - let me know.

Answer (score 3):

For your:

**Problem 1** you can add `contentType: 'application/json;'` in your ajax request for the controller to know how to parse your request.

**Problem 2** see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmvtrinidad/89ej0vjk/1/) for example of your code. You can check this [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) in order for you to know where to use different binding context.

Comment: Regarding content type - it's not a problem. Because controller receive information about elements that not observableArray in Vm and there already is dataType provided. Regarding problem nr. 2 I already read that documentation , I need an example of my goal